# Is there a way how i can find the index of an multidimensional numpy array by matching it to another numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Lets say i have the following case:

```
array1=np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
array2=np.array([0,0,1])
```

now

```
array1[2]
```

gives me the output

```
[0,0,1]
```

so now i want to have code that gives the index of `array1` (in this case `2`) as the output for matching `array2` to `array1`.
Is there any elegant way to do this? i tried `numpy.where` but didn't get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly. But you could either do this:

```
import numpy as np
np.where((array2 == array1).all(axis=1))
```

You can do this:

```
index = np.argmax([0,0,1])
```

Or use this:

```
indices = np.where(np.array([0,0,1]) == 1)
```

Comment: but this just gives me the index of the 1 in this one array. i want to find the index of [0,0,1] in another array.

Comment: Can you rewrite your question to state your task precisely?

Answer (score 0):

`mask=np.all(array1 == array2, axis=1)` will give you an array to True and False. This will flag True where the condition matches. You can search the index of all 'True' by using `ind=np.argwhere(mask)`. In a way this is the same answer as @sehan2.